# Could someone explain the algebra in this sequences problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$$ \frac{(n^2+n)-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n} = \frac{n}{n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1\right)} $$

The advantage here is that the n's cancel, but I don't see why the argument of the sqrt() function ends up becoming $$ 1 + \frac{1}{n} $$

Comment: I mistyped the numerator. My edits now reflect that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} = \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2(1+1/n^2)}+n} =$$
$$=\frac{n}{n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1} $$

Answer (score 0):

You have $\sqrt {n^2 + n}$ what you are doing is factoring out $n^2$ from this expression which will give you

$$\sqrt {n^2 \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)} = \sqrt {n^2 + \frac{n^2}{n}} = \sqrt{n^2 + n}$$

Multiplying out you'll see clearly that you'll end up with the factored expression.

Since it is under the square root, the $n^2$ term simply becomes $n (\sqrt {n^2} = n)$

So that is how you end up with

$$\frac{n}{n \sqrt {1+\frac{1}{n}} +n} = \frac{n}{n \left( \sqrt {1+\frac{1}{n}} +1\right)}$$

In this step you factor out $n$ from $n\sqrt {1+\frac{1}{n}}$ and $n$.